# How can a medium-voltage solid state relay be used in a HV circuit?

Tags: solid-state-relay, hvdc

Adrian Marsh has [a recent video about a VTTC with fractal fern discharges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si5iVaRG0wc&t=1762s). Incidentally, he talks about introducing a medium-voltage solid-state relay into the circuit which includes a high voltage power triode (the link leads directly to that part of the video).

But how is it supposed to work? The SSR-40DA relay is rated only for a few hundred volts. So, as soon as the relay is switched off, it's going to have a much higher voltage across it than what it's rated for, and will just get destroyed. That's what seems to me, at least.

This idea of using a relay that way is also mentioned on [his website](https://www.am-innovations.com/category/generators/generators-vacuum-tube/) as "cathode keying" by semiconductor MOSFET switches.

Here is the diagram of the circuit, and the relay is shown as a switch between the cathode and the ground: [image]

Comment: Please show diagram where the SSR is connected.